# Theano scan function and argument number lstm

Tags: python, theano, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am new to Neural Networks and I am trying to modify this code [RNN-Classifier](https://github.com/marekrei/theano-tutorial%20das%20Programm%20rnnclassifier.py) and instead of using the GRU_step, I would rather use an LSTM.

I added one extra parameter **c_prev**

```
        def lstm_step(x, h_prev, c_prev, W_xz, W_hz, W_xm, W_hm):
```

and after applying all the LSTM equations I am returning them both (h and c)

My hidden vector looks like that:

```
        hidden_vector, _ = theano.scan(
        lstm_step,
        sequences=input_vectors,
        outputs_info=initial_hidden_vector,
        non_sequences=[W_xz, W_hz, W_xm, W_hm]
    )
    hidden_vector = hidden_vector[-1]
```

I get an exception like this and don't understand why it does not see the c_prev as an existant parameter (or how/where can I feed it with some values, so that it's not empty?)

```
python rnnclassifier.py data/sentiment.train.txt data/sentiment.test.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "rnnclassifier.py", line 167, in <module>
rnn_classifier = RnnClassifier(word2id_len, n_classes)

File "rnnclassifier.py", line 110, in __init__
non_sequences=[W_xz, W_hz, W_xm, W_hm]

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/scan_module/scan.py",
line 773, in scan condition, outputs, updates =   
scan_utils.get_updates_and_outputs(fn(*args))

TypeError: lstm_step() takes exactly 7 arguments (6 given)
```

I am new to this topic and would appreciate any help or advice! Thank you.

Comment: SOLVED: I put the c_prev in the scan-function (outputs_info) to be updated